# Como faço pra criar uma legenda que mostra o conteúdo da coluna no banco de dados?

Tags: php

Criei uma tabela que exibe todos os funcionários cadastrados no banco de dados, eu queria usar o atributo `title` dentro das `<td>` para criar uma **legenda exata do que está dentro das colunas da tabela**.

Ex: Ao arrastar o mouse na coluna **Nome** com campo `João` a legenda mostraria `João` ao invés de `[nome]`.

A linha que falo de exemplo é:

```
echo '<td title="[nome]">'.$exibir_colunas['nome'].'</td>';
```

```
<?php
        require_once '../conexao/conexao.php';

        try {
            $selecao = "SELECT * FROM funcionario";
            $seleciona_dados = $conexao->prepare($selecao);
            $seleciona_dados->execute();
            $linhas = $seleciona_dados->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
        } catch (PDOException $falha_selecao) {
            echo "A listagem de dados não foi feita".$falha_selecao->getMessage();
            die;
        } catch (Exception $falha) {
            echo "Erro não característico do PDO".$falha->getMessage();
            die;
        }
    ?>
    <table border="1">
        <tr> 
            <th title="ID"> ID </th> 
            <th title="Nome"> Nome </th> 
            <th title="Cargo"> Cargo </th>
            <th title="CPF"> CPF </th> 
            <th title="Telefone"> Telefone </th>
            <th title="Email"> Email </th>
            <th title="Ações"> Ações </th>
        </tr>
        <?php 
            foreach ($linhas as $exibir_colunas){
                echo '<tr>';
                echo '<td title="[cd_funcionario]">'.$exibir_colunas['cd_funcionario'].'</td>';
                echo '<td title="[nome]">'.$exibir_colunas['nome'].'</td>';
                echo '<td title="[cargo]">'.$exibir_colunas['cargo'].'</td>';
                echo '<td title="[cpf]">'.$exibir_colunas['cpf'].'</td>';
                echo '<td title="[telefone]">'.$exibir_colunas['telefone'].'</td>';
                echo '<td title="[email]">'.$exibir_colunas['email'].'</td>';
                echo '<td>'."<a href='../crud/form_insert_funcionario.php' title='Cadastrar funcionário'>INSERT</a> ".
                "<a href='../crud/form_select_funcionario.php' title='Listar funcionários'>SELECT</a> ".
                "<a href='../crud/form_update_funcionario.php' title='Atualizar funcionário'>UPDATE</a> ".
                "<a href='../crud/form_delete_funcionario.php' title='Deletar funcionário'>DELETE</a>".'</td>';
                echo '</tr>'; echo '</p>';
            }
        ?>
    </table>
```

Comment: Ué, é só colocar $exibir_colunas['nome'] em vez de [nome] que está no title dentro do foreach. Igual você fez para aparecer joao no td

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```php
echo '<td title="'.$exibir_colunas['nome'].'">'.$exibir_colunas['nome'].'</td>';
```

Comment: Obrigado ai cara, me ajudou na minha dúvida.